# error en script con jquery y php (validar formulario)

Tags: php, html, jquery

veran estoy usando el plugin -> https://jqueryvalidation.org/ para validar un formulario pero no logro entender que estoy haciendo mala para verificar el usuario si existe segun la consola es un error de jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#ok").hide();

$("#signup").validate({
    rules: {
        username: { required: true, minlength: 3,
            remote: {url: "pages/registro.php", type: "post", 
                data:{
                    username: function(){return $("#username").val();}
                }
            }
        },
        pass: { required: true, minlength: 7},
        passR: {equalTo: "#pass"},
        nombre: { required:true},
        codigoB: { required:true, minlength: 7, maxlength: 7, digits: true},
        email: { required:true, email: true},
        edad: { required:true},
        pais: { required:true}
    },
    messages: {
        username: 'min. 3 caracteres.',
        pass: "min. 7 caracteres .",
        passR: "algo esta mal!",
        nombre : "Requerido.",
        codigoB : "número de 7 dígitos.",
        email : "Debe introducir un email válido."
    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        var dataString = 'username='+$('#username').val()+'&pass='+$('#pass').val()+'&nombre='+$('#nombre').val()+'&codigoB='+$('#codigoB').val()+'&email='+$('#email').val()+'&edad='+$('#edad').val()+'&pais='+$('#pais').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"pages/registro.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data){
                $("#ok").html(data);
                $("#ok").show();
                $("#signup").hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

y el codigo php

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
        $user = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        if(!validar_usuario($user)){echo 'true';}else{echo 'false';}    
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué error sale en la consola y dónde?

Comment: al darle inspecionar sale esto "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element , check the 'remote' method"

Comment: Como el problema esta en remote prueba username: $("#username").val(); si funciona el problema puede estar en lo que te retorna

Comment: no funciona mantiene el mismo error :/

Answer (score 0):

Ajax no permite enviar strings como parámetro, sino que hay que manderle en forma de objeto. Tendrás que cambiar la forma de enviar la data a esta forma:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"pages/registro.php",
            data: {"username": dataString },
            success: function(data){
                $("#ok").html(data);
                $("#ok").show();
                $("#signup").hide();
            }
        });
```

Por otro lado no entiendo muy bien por qué creas la variable dataString con los "&". Pero eso podría darte algún fallo en el php a posterior.

Comment: Los datos se pueden pasar como objeto o como string, esto no responde a la pregunta.

Comment: la verdad estoy aprendiendo javascript, jquery y ajax y se me complica un poco